# Multiple JRE on a system

Tags: java

I am using a windows machine with multiple version of JRE installed.

If I run an eclipse RCP application, which version of JRE it will be using, the latest JRE version or the one mentioned under `JAVA_HOME` in `Environment Variables -> System Variables`?

Comment: the first one in the Variables, as i remember in the System variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `eclipse.ini` file in the Eclipse installation directory, you can add the lines:

```
-vm
C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_09_x64/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Of course, adjust the path to the JDK / JRE you want Eclipse to use.

[EDIT] Re-reading your question, I notice you mention "*and eclipse RCP application*", so perhaps you mean something else than Eclipse. The answer might be different then.
I suggest you add more tags (and improve the subject) to reflect better the scope of your question.

[EDIT] From a quick research, it seems that Eclipse RPC applications also use an .ini file (that's the case of the Eclipse Memory Analyzer I have on my disk), so my trick above might work... It might depend on the launcher you want to use, too.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will be executed in the VM defined in `JAVA_HOME` by default.

But you may change the JRE/JDK, programs are executed/compiled with under Eclipse > Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.

Answer (score 1):

It must be using the default JRE that's available in your OS path first unless you override it by specifying -vm arg in .ini file.